# Issue With Using Multiple Custom Authenticated Accounts via AWS iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

We are building an app in iOS 9 that uses `AWS` as a backend.
The system is using custom authentication via Lambda (loosely based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBxWZ9bgd44 and https://github.com/awslabs/api-gateway-secure-pet-store ), and on success cognito credentials are returned to be used for calls to `AWS (API Gateway)`.  The app uses a custom credentials provider and when a user successfully logs in this is what is being done to set up the user/session to make future calls to the system's `AWS` backend for the session:

// The SystemUserCredentials class holds the entered username and password from the UIView

```
let userCredentials: SystemUserCredentials = SystemUserCredentials(username, password)
// CustomAwsSessionCredentialProvider inherits AWSCredentialsProvider
let apiCredsProvider = CustomAwsSessionCredentialsProvider(credentials: userCredentials)
let defaultConfig = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: apiCredsProvider)
// API_CLIENT_CONFIG_KEY is a constant for the configuration key
SystemAPIClient.registerClientWithConfiguration(defaultConfig, forKey: API_CLIENT_CONFIG_KEY)
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultConfig
```

And that initial user can communicate with our authenticated AWS backend with no problem.

What is being noticed is that when a user logs out with one valid account (the initial one when the app loaded), and then the user tries to log in with a different valid account there are failures in communicating with the [authenticated] web methods, and it looks like it is because the app is still trying to use the cognito credentials from the first/initial session. I did find this comment in AWS's API SDK which I believe is causing the issue: The default service configuration object. This property can be set only once, and any subsequent setters are ignored.

My initial thoughts are to move away from using the `defaultServiceManager` and its
`defaultServiceConfiguration` and going with non-default key-based services, clients, 
configuration, etc.

My question is - has anyone else run into this, and is there a simpler way to use multiple
custom-authenticated clients in an app using the default service manager and 
configuration?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this sample? https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/developer-authenticated-identities-2-4/CognitoSync-Sample/Swift/CognitoSyncDemo/DeveloperAuthenticated/DeveloperAuthenticatedIdentityProvider.m

Comment: I hadn't, thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: You mention authenticated Cognito calls, but I'm not sure I follow where. Is your provider a developer authenticated one?

Comment: @core_rick71 , Have you resolved this problem? I have the same issue.